# 同名の純粋仮想関数を持つ抽象クラスの継承時に、それぞれ異なる実装を記述する方法はありますか?

Tags: c++

以下のような抽象クラス Interface1, Interface2 があります。

```
class Interface1
{
public:
    virtual void Function() = 0;
};

class Interface2
{
public:
    virtual void Function() = 0;
};
```

これら2つの抽象クラスを多重継承するクラス Implementation があります。

```
class Implementation :
    public Interface1,
    public Interface2
{
    // Interface1 としての Function() の振る舞いを実装したい

    // Interface2 としての Function() 振る舞いを実装したい
}
```

Implementation のコメントの通り、Interface1::Function() と Interaface2::Function() にそれぞれ異なる実装を与える方法はありますでしょうか?

例えば、Interface1, Interaface2 は以下のように使われます。

```
template<typename T>
class InterfaceCaller
{
public:
    void Register(T* pInterface)
    {
        m_List.push_back(pInterface);
    }

    void Call()
    {
        for(auto& interface : m_List)
        {
            interface->Function();
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<T*> m_List;
};
```

`InterfaceCaller<Interface1>::Register(Implementation);` としたとき、`InterfaceCaller<Interface1>::Call()` では、「Interface1 としての Function() の振る舞い」が呼ばれるようにしたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

抽象クラス`Interface1`, `Interface2`に手を入れられない場合、クラス継承関係に中間層を設ける方法が考えられます。

下記コードでは`ProxyInterface1`クラスによって`Interface1::Function`を`Function1`に、`ProxyInterface2`によって`Interface2::Function`を`Function2`に処理委譲し、個別にオーバーライド可能としています。
Proxyクラスの`Function`オーバーライドでは`final`指定を行うことで、`Implementation::Function`で再度オーバーライドされるミスを防いでいます。

```cpp
class Interface1
{
public:
    virtual void Function() = 0;
};

class Interface2
{
public:
    virtual void Function() = 0;
};

class ProxyInterface1 : public Interface1
{
    virtual void Function() override final { Function1(); }
    virtual void Function1() = 0;
};

class ProxyInterface2 : public Interface2
{
    virtual void Function() override final { Function2(); }
    virtual void Function2() = 0;
};

class Implementation :
    public ProxyInterface1,
    public ProxyInterface2
{
    virtual void Function1() override { std::cout << "Interface1::Function\n"; }
    virtual void Function2() override { std::cout << "Interface2::Function\n"; }
};
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/jKvkWFYrN2PKmtb6

Comment: ありがごうございます。ずばり頂いた回答で問題を解決できそうです。
final 指定はご指摘いただかなければ抜けてしまっていたと思います。

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++の場合、[明示的なオーバーライド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/cpp/explicit-overrides-cpp?view=vs-2019)という機能が提供されていて、メンバー関数名にクラス名を付与できます。

```
class Implementation :
    public Interface1,
    public Interface2
{
    // Interface1 としての Function() の振る舞いを実装したい
    void Interface1::Function() override {
        std::cout << "Interface1::Function\n";
    }

    // Interface2 としての Function() 振る舞いを実装したい
    void Interface2::Function() override {
        std::cout << "Interface2::Function\n";
    }
};
```

.NET Runtime仕様としてこのような継承が認められているため、それを実現するためにVisual C++コンパイラにも実装されており、その際、非.NET環境にも同様に記述できるように言語拡張されているようです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
VC++ だとこの方法で名前解決できるのですね。
明記しておらず申し訳ないのですが、残念ながらコンパイラ拡張に依存することができないため、この方法を採用することはできませんでした。

余談ですが、こういう場面ってままありそうなんですが、コンパイラ拡張なんですね…。言語仕様には取り込まれないんだろうか。